# Inherited Class Properties Returning NULL

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes: **News** and **NewsComments**. When I instantiate the **News** class, I pass the ID of the news post like this:

```
$News = new News($_POST['news_id']);
```

Then I instantiate the **NewsComments** class underneath it with this code:

```
$NewsComments = new NewsComments($_POST['comment_id']);
```

Here is the **News** class code.

```
class News extends Privilege
{
    public function __construct($id = null) {
        if(!is_null($id))
            $this->news_id = $id;
    }
}
```

Then there's the child class, NewsComments.

```
class NewsComments extends News
{
    public function testFunction() {
        return $this->news_id; // This will return null
    }
}
```

For some reason, I cannot access the $this->news_id variable in the **NewsComments** child class, even though it *extends* the **News** class. I did a *var_dump* on *$this->news_id* in one of my files that deletes a news comment, but it returns *NULL*. I checked to make sure *$_POST['id']* is not NULL by replacing it with the number 7 (which is the ID of an existing news post), yet I get the same error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: NewsComments::$news_id
```

Both the **news.php** and **newscomments.php** files are included in the script, and no errors are present indicating they failed to be included. I've tried many things, such as adding **parent::__construct()** in the constructor method of my child class, **NewsComments**. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I marked it as duplicate, but I'm a bit confused by the way you use these classes. Even if a class extends from another class, it doesn't get access to properties of another *instance* of the class. I think the examples in the other question should help you, but if now, please clarify this subject by editing your question (and including a bit more of your code), or asking a new and improved question.

Comment: I read that question, however none of the solutions worked. I see what you mean about my question being similar, though. I now realize that passing a property to the constructor method of the parent class doesn't inherit to the child class. However, I need to access that property since it contains the ID of the news post, which is relevant for news comments. I suppose I can always try to instantiate the news_id variable in the NewsComments class.

I have to apologize as I am new to OOP and this site. Would it be best to delete this question or leave it for archival purposes?

Comment: No problem, it's okay to leave it. Future visitors who find it will at least have the link to the other question which may or may not help them.